# Problem running RoR app in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel, production-environment

Have an app that has "listings" - think classified ads - and each listing has a list of tags.

The following code fails when I run the app in production mode, but works fine under development mode

```
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Acts::Taggable::InstanceMethods::TagList
Extracted source (around line #45):

42:         
43:         <span class="listingIndexTags">
44:             Location: [location] | Tags:
45:             <% tag_list = listing.tag_list %>
46:             <% if tag_list != nil %> 
47:                 <% for tag in tag_list %>
48:                     <%= link_to tag.to_s, { :action => "filter_on",
```

The command line I'm using to start my mongrel instance in this test case:
ruby script/server mongrel -e production

Defaults to port 3000. I can access other views in the app that *DON'T* call "listing.tag_list".

".tag_list" is provided by "acts_as_taggable_on_steroids", which I'm using in this app. It is installed as a gem.

Maybe my environment files are wonky?

Here's my development.rb file

```
config.cache_classes = false

config.whiny_nils = true

config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
config.action_view.debug_rjs                         = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = false

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  ...took these settings out for this post...
}
```

And my production.rb file...

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.threadsafe!  

config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = true

config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  ...took these settings out for this post...
}
```

Comment: This almost certainly has to do with the cache_classes setting. To narrow it down, what happens if you turn off class caching in production? In addition, what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: it's possible that the error will appear on the development machine if you drop and rebuild the database.  I often run into problems like this and it's because the development database contains older entries that satisfy certain needs of the application but the production database doesn't contain them because it's fresh.  Sometimes as an app grows, we alter the code in such a way that it will fail when the database is empty...  just a shot in the dark if all else fails.

Comment: also, what kind of tests (integration in particular) do you have?  the suggestion above would not be needed if your tests were adequate and passing

Comment: @Randy: I've tried turning class caching off, and restarting the Mongrel in production mode. No change in symptoms.

Comment: @Stephen: I've actually copied my sqlite3 database, and pasted it as "production.sqlite3", so the databases are identical in this case.

Maybe that's part of my issue as well - straight up copying of the databases, might be a big no-no?

To answer your test question, you're absolutely right. I don't have tests covering this - in fact, integration_tests.size == 0 at this moment - so bad, bad developer I am. So I need to write them, and fix it.

Any additional comments on copying of the database, as a side note?

Comment: Wrote my functional tests. But there's not change. It works fine in my test environment as well - only seems to break in the Production environment. I'll keep poking around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED:

Well, after putting off fixing this bug until I absolutely had to (today), I at long last found the source of the issue.

The inclusion of the line:
config.threadsafe!

In my "production.rb" file was causing it.

```
I finally found it by:
    1. Making my production and development environment files identical
    2. Line-by-line, changing the production environment file until it either:
      a. The app broke in production mode
      b. I was back to my original production file
```

Anyhow, when I got to adding the "config.threadsafe!" line - IT BROKE! I was never so happy to have an app break.

So, a little reading to understand what exactly this option does, in conjuction with Mongrel (if Mongrel is even relevant), and I'll have my answer.

Comment: Great job. I had the same problem here. Damn `threadsafe!` setting from an old JRuby deployment we tried.

Answer (score 1):

Came along here with the same problem and just wanted to hand a note to everyone experiencing the same....I've managed to sort this problem this by fixing the version of gems in environment.rb

changed this
config.gem "acts-as-taggable-on", :source => "http://gemcutter.org"

to this:
config.gem "acts-as-taggable-on", :source => "http://gemcutter.org", :version => '2.0.0.rc1'

and run a rake gems:install

I wonder if you somehow were running different gems on different environments if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `acts_as_taggable_on_steroids` gem installed on your production server?

Comment: I do. The same thing happens on my development machine, as it turns out, when I start mongrel in "production" environment, so nothing specific to the server as it turns out.

I've also got the 'config.gem "acts_as_taggable_on_steroids' line in my environment.rb file, so I would expect that it would apply to all environments, if I'm understanding that properly.

Comment: So is the gem listed if you run `gem list` on the server?